# insert query store 0 in all fields

Tags: php, mysql

When I create this api and image name consist with `projectid`,`user_id`,`category` but I can't save image in database because image `project_id`,`image_id`,`image` not properly getting from `POST` method.please help thanks in advance

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once('confi.php');
    //Destination of images
    define('IMG_DESTINATION',dirname(__FILE__).'/images/');
    define('DB_NAME','chat_neeraj');
    //Saving Data to Image Table
    function saveImageData($data,$imgFile){
                $project_id = isset($_POST['project_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['project_id']) : "";
                $image_id = isset($_POST['image_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_id']) : "";
                //$user_id = isset($_POST['user_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']) : "";
                $image_name = isset($_POST['image_name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_name']) : "";
                if(isset($_FILES['tmp_name']) && filesize($_FILES['tmp_name'])>0)
                    saveImageFile($imgFile['tmp_name'],$image_id."_".$project_id."_".$category_id."_".$image_name);
                $category_id = isset($_POST['category_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category_id']) : "";
                $houssup_id = isset($_POST['houssup_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['houssup_id']) : "";
                $location_id = isset($_POST['location_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location_id']) : "";
                // Insert data into data base
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `".DB_NAME."`.`image_table`(`project_id`, `image_id`,`image_name`,`category_id`,`houssup_id`,`location_id`) 
                VALUES(NULL,'$image_id','$image_name','$category_id','$houssup_id','$location_id')";
                echo $sql;
                if(mysql_query($sql))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
    }

    //Saving Image file to Diskk
    function saveImageFile($src,$des){
        copy($src,$dest);
    }
    //Select Image
    function selectImage(){

    }

    //Save Image Hash Tag
    function saveImageHashTag(){
    }

    $action=isset($_REQUEST['action'])?$_REQUEST['action']:"";
    switch($action){
        case "save":
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST)){
                if(saveImageData($_POST,$_FILES)){
                    echo "Saved";
                }else{
                    echo "Failed";
                }
            }else{  
                echo "Nothing to Save";
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo "Live";
            break;

    } 
    //Closing DB Connection
    if($conn){
        @mysql_close($conn);
    }
```

Comment: DB_NAME is a database or a table?

Comment: What is the error? @Shruti Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO image_table ('project_id', 'image_id','image_name','category_id','houssup_id','location_id')           VALUES(NULL,$image_id,'$image_name',$category_id,$houssup_id,$location_id)";
```

Answer (score 0):

On you function definition:

```
function saveImageData($data,$imgFile){
```

Here the first parameter is `$data`, so inside your function it would be `$data` not `$_POST`. Replace all `$_POST` and `$_FILES` with `$data` and `$imgFile` inside your function implementation. It will work.

Reason: you are calling it like: `if(saveImageData($_POST,$_FILES)){`

So, within your function definition, `$_POST` is available as `$data` and `$_FILES` is available as `$imgFile`.

**Updated Code:**

```
    <?php
    //Saving Data to Image Table
    function saveImageData($data,$imgFile){
                $project_id = isset($data['project_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['project_id']) : "";
                $image_id = isset($data['image_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['image_id']) : "";
                //$user_id = isset($data['user_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['user_id']) : "";
                $image_name = isset($data['image_name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['image_name']) : "";
                if(isset($imgFile['tmp_name']) && filesize($imgFile['tmp_name'])>0)
                    saveImageFile($imgFile['tmp_name'],$image_id."_".$project_id."_".$category_id."_".$image_name);
                $category_id = isset($data['category_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['category_id']) : "";
                $houssup_id = isset($data['houssup_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['houssup_id']) : "";
                $location_id = isset($data['location_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data['location_id']) : "";
                // Insert data into data base
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `".DB_NAME."`.`image_table`(`project_id`, `image_id`,`image_name`,`category_id`,`houssup_id`,`location_id`) 
                VALUES(NULL,'$image_id','$image_name','$category_id','$houssup_id','$location_id')";
                echo $sql;
                if(mysql_query($sql))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
    }
```